# How can I keep the loose ends of backpack straps from blowing around?

Tags: backpacks

I love my Osprey backpack but the waist belt is too long so the extra strapping ends up being about 2' long and annoying.  I've avoided cutting it and have been tucking it into a pocket on the waste belt but would like to find a better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5474/2653

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace Good find - I couldn't.

Comment: 2 feet is a lot. I would definitely cut at least one of those feet off. You're never going use the extra strap, not unless you plan on gaining, *literally*, 48 inches on your hips.

Comment: @mattsolar I knew we had the other question some weeks ago. But I still had to search some minutes so it indeed wasn't that easy to find ;)

Answer (score 0):

interesting question. I usually carry a couple things like GPS and knife that loop onto the belt, so these things actually keep the strap ends in check. ... But if I didn't have these things, I'd probably do one of two things:

- use a small Velcro strap (so called "cable ties" that you can purchase at computer or office supply store)

or

- try to find some of those hard plastic "clamp" things that sometimes come with the straps, I wish I knew what they were called, but it's basically just a hard circular loop that slides up and down the belt or the strap. I'm sure there's gotta be someplace that sells these in different sizes. Maybe someone here knows the official name for them